# iOS disable Highlighted Imageview

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, tableview, highlight

I am using `Swift` and have a `UITableview` which has a custom `UITableViewCell` with an `UIImageview`. By mistake I have set the highlighted image to some image. I want to disable the highlighted functionality as I need to do something else when I tap the image. There should be no highlighting on tap. I am sure its a simple one line code but can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it elsewhere:
in the tap function with the taprecognizer, just need to add the following line:

```
imageView.highlightedImage = nil
```